# XSLT Identity Transform: Delete element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to xslt and I am trying to delete the element 'Input' from the following xml

My Input XML:

```
<ns1:Input xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.org/">
     <Process xmlns="http://www.acord.org/...."  
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.acord.org/schema/... ">
    .....
    </Process>
</ns1:Input>
```

Expected output :

```
<Process xmlns="http://www.acord.org/...." 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.acord.org/schema/... ">
         .....
 </Process>
```

I am using Identity transform like,

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

So it is copying the whole xml in to target xsd but it is copying with 'input' element which I want to remove.
Appreciate any quick help.

Thanks,
cdhar

Answer (score 0):

Add a template

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:Input">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

In any case you might get the root namespace declaration on the `Process` element so with XSLT 2.0 you might need to use `<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">...` in your identity transformation (http://xsltransform.net/bFN1yag)

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:Input" xmlns:ns1="http://www.test.org/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

or you need to create elements in XSLT 1.0 with `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">` instead of the `xsl:copy`.

Comment: Thanks a ton Martin. Works like a charm. Thank you!!